# AngularJS: How do I check if date exist in array and return id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to check if the current date exists in an array and return id which exists on the same index where date exists.

The below code is not working to check the element, I have already tried `includes()`

```
  const results = []; 
angular.forEach(getEventdate, function(value)
{
results.push({id:value.id,event_date:value.event_date}); });

    if(results.some(result => result.event_date === current_date)) 
{ 
console.log('date exists!'); 
}
```

Sample array:

```
0: {id: 4, event_date: "2019-01-11"}
1: {id: 6, event_date: "2019-01-11"}
2: {id: 7, event_date: "2019-01-11"}
3: {id: 8, event_date: "2017-06-13"}
4: {id: 9, event_date: "2017-06-14"}
5: {id: 10, event_date: "2017-06-21"}
6: {id: 11, event_date: "2017-06-22"}
7: {id: 12, event_date: "2017-06-23"}
8: {id: 13, event_date: "2017-06-26"}
9: {id: 14, event_date: "2017-06-27"}
```

I need `id` if a current date exists in the array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$filter`.

```
var d = new Date();
var filteredDate = $filter('date')(d, 'yyyy-M-d');
var foundId = (array.filter(function(item) {
    return item.event_date === filteredDate;
})[0] || {}).id;
```

This will return undefined if the date is not found.

You will need to inject `$filter` into your controller.

Comment: I replaced 'data' with my source array but its not working

Comment: @JKLM I apologize, I misspelled `data`. It's supposed to be `date`. It's a string telling the $filter function which filter to use. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With ES2015+ you can use `find` to get the `id` when it's found and `undefined` otherwise.

```
const { id } = values.find(item => item.event_date === currentDate) || {};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the very first occurrence of the date then try using `find`, or if you want all the occurrences matching the date then try using `filter`.

e.g. using `find`

```
const {id} = results.find(val=>{
   return val.event_date === someDateString;
})
```

Filter will return array of all the occurrences matching that value.

```
const dates=results.filter(val=>{
    return val.event_date === someDateString;
})
```